# Zend_Request to String

Tags: request, zend-framework

i want convert my obj Zend_Request to a sting, like ...

```
$request = new Zend_Http_Client('http://mysite.com');

$request->setParameterGet('param1', 'test1');
$request->setParameterGet('param2', 'test2');
$request->setParameterGet('param3', 'test3');
```

I want see like this string..

```
echo '<pre>';
$request->toStringMethod().....
```

Result wanted:

```
http://mysite.com?param1=test1&=param2=test2&=param2=test2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http_build_query to create a query string. For example `http_build_query($request->getQuery())`

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php